# How to turn on/off Cellular Network Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to refresh android Cellular Network android, but gets error. i want to make it working.

my code:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, mode ? 1 : 0);// Turning ON/OFF Airplane mode.

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);// creating intent and Specifying action for AIRPLANE mode.
        intent.putExtra("state", !mode);// indicate the "state" of airplane mode is changed to ON/OFF
        sendBroadcast(intent);// Broadcasting and Intent
```

my manifest file has permission.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Error:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.zt.refreshnetwork, PID: 20221
                                                                       java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=20221, uid=10237
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3537)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:881)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:421)
                                                                           at com.zt.refreshnetwork.MainActivity.modifyAirplanemode(MainActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at com.zt.refreshnetwork.MainActivity.airPlanemodeON(MainActivity.java:117)
                                                                           at com.zt.refreshnetwork.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10237 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.>` seems like a pretty strong hint.

Comment: Looking at the Logcat, you need the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission, but this is only available to system apps or on rooted devices ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Michael not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=20221, uid=10237

Comment: @MichaelDodd not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=20221, uid=10237

Comment: @SamirPatel OK, please update your question to show the code that sends the `AIRPLANE_MODE` broadcast (method `modifyAirplanemode`).

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to modify Airplane Mode programmatically as of Android 4.2: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers

Comment: @MichaelDodd Please install this app, it allows https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atejapps.networksignalrefresher&hl=en

Comment: I'll pass thanks. So you're saying that app "refreshes" your mobile signal by enabling then disabling airplane mode?

Comment: ok thanks for your efforts sir but i want to know how does it work if it doesn't work by airplane mode

Comment: The benefits of Signal Booster apps have long been the subject of discussion regardless. This article from 12th May 2016 tests out 8 booster apps, finds that the benefits are minimal at best, and actively harm data speeds at worst: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-net-speed-boosters-review/

Comment: @MichaelDodd im not talking about internet and its speed. i want to refresh network . i mean on off cellular network programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are attempting to modify the Airplane Mode status. This has been removed to third-party apps as of Android 4.2. [From the release notes:](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers)

> Several existing settings were relocated here from either `Settings.System` or `Settings.Secure`. If your app is currently making changes to settings previously defined in `Settings.System` (such as `AIRPLANE_MODE_ON`), then you should expect that doing so will no longer work on a device running Android 4.2 or higher if those settings were moved to `Settings.Global`.
>
> You can continue to read settings that are in `Settings.Global`, but because the settings are no longer considered safe for apps to change, attempting to do so will fail silently and the system will write a warning to the system log when running your app on Android 4.2 or higher.

Chances are you'll need to rely on reflection and digging around the AOSP source if you absolutely want to do this, but Google usually make these sorts changes for sound security reasons. Any attempt to circumvent these measures could result in your app being removed from the Play store, or may result in your app not working at all with future releases of Android if underlying methods change.

Likewise, in the original version of your question, your app was requesting the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission. Again, this is not available to third party apps, only System apps, which would require this app to be run on a rooted device. [From the documentation (my bold):](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)

> Allows modification of the telephony state - power on, mmi, etc. Does not include placing calls.
> **Not for use by third-party applications.**

Comment: Please check   this app. its working in Nougat.    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atejapps.networksignalrefresher&hl=en

Comment: You would need to contact the developers of the app to ascertain what methods they use.